# Application class in a module's manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have added a module within my project and created an Application class which was added to the module's manifest.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());;
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mymodule">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.example.mymodule.App">
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is that I get no suggestions when trying to set the name of my application class within the Manifest. Any ideas why?

EDIT: I already have an Application class in my app module. The reason why I'm doing this is because I want to add a library in that module. How can I achieve this?

Comment: there might be package difference

Comment: it's the same package

Comment: Restart you Android studio, or clean your project. Sometimes Android Studio has problems with suggestion

Comment: did it, no effect

Comment: can you please let me know the first line, which is package name, in your **App.java** class?

Comment: The same package name as shown in the Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You need to type . (dot) and then you will get the suggestion. Like below

```
android:name=".App"
```

Comment: Tried it but I get no suggestions at all.

Comment: Can you please share the package name of your Application class ? It is at the top of the class

Comment: it's com.example.mymodule

Comment: then there must be some issue with studio which version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

If you application class is within any package then the name will be 
.[package name].[Application class]. If it is outside the any package the just the Application name.If still the problem exist then restart the studio  sync,rebuild and clean it and check it once again.Hope this will help you.